# Android turn off ChromeCast Screen Mirroring function

Tags: android, chromecast

I have a problem with ChromeCast Screen Mirroring function. Because my content is protected (DRM video) if the user use Screen Cast i need check and turn off or show something else (like protected content message picture) and not the video.

My question is: Its possible detect Screen Mirroring and disable in code?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement Chromecast-support in your app and choose which layout to cast when the screen is mirrored (so just cast an empty layout or information etc). If you check the example PresentationWithMediaRouterActivity in Android ApiDemos (or Google it and you will find the files needed), you can see a good example implementation that does just that.