# How to programmatically block chromecast / MHL screen mirroring in an app?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, mirroring

In Java, is it possible to block an Android applications screen being mirrored in chromecast or via an MHL connection?

I've tried FLAG_SECURE as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/5983905

however that only blanks the app for Miracast mode. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about trying the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620764/android-turn-off-chromecast-screen-mirroring-function)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I tried that and it works ok in a 1 activity app but when transitioning between activities I get the underlying activity showing, which doesn't look good.